# Send message through Socket Outputstream from Swift Client to Java Server

Tags: java, swift, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

As the title says, I'm having some problems connecting my Swift Client to a Java Server by using only native libraries.

Right now I have a Java(client) to Java(server) connection, which works flawlessly, and a Swift(client) to Java(server) connection. My Swift client does connect to the Java server (it shows on the console), but the readFully of my server hangs -  the only thing I see is the enormous message length on the console and that's pretty much it.

Swift Code (send):

```
func send(message: String) {
  let data = "msg:\(message)".data(using: .utf8)!

    data.withUnsafeBytes {
    guard let pointer = $0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) else {
      print("Error joining chat")
      return
    }
    out!.write(pointer, maxLength: data.count)
  }
}
```

Java Server (read):

```
int lenght = in.readInt();
System.out.println("Message: " + lenght);
if(length>0){
 byte[] message = new byte[length];
 in.readFully(message), 0, message.length); //This is where the problem is
}
```

So, basically the Java server hangs on the readFully method. Any ideas why that is? Whether I send a simple String or a Byte array, it always hangs, and for some reason the length is extremely big. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong because I've around this for days and still didn't understand it (still pretty new to Swift).

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sweeper that's a good catch! Any idea on how I can first send the message length and then only the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Java code, you expect the first 4 bytes to be the length of the message, but in the Swift code, you didn't send the length of the message first. You sent the message itself directly. So now the Java code is left confused as to why the message is shorter than it expected, and waiting for more data to read.

You can try sending the number of bytes in `data` first:

```
let byteCountAsByteArray = withUnsafeBytes(of: Int32(data.count).bigEndian, Array.init)
out!.write(byteCountAsByteArray, maxLength: 4)
out!.write(pointer, maxLength: data.count)
```

I suspect that you are using a `DataInputStream` in your Java code, hence `.bigEndian`. But if you are reading this in a little endian way, use `.littleEndian` instead.

Comment: Yes! Exactly this! Yeah, using DataInputStream as you guessed. Working wonderfully now! Thank you very much!

Comment: @JCCA If `write`  writes into a socket, chances are that not all bytes will be written. So, since it actually is a socket, your code has to make changes to work correctly - unless you already implemented `write` in a way that blocks the thread and takes care of this under the hood - which would not be a good solution, though.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper What kind of changes? It does write into a socket, but from what I see  from both sides, the message is the same on both, so I would suppose everything is ok. But I'm not exactly an expert on this! Thank you!

Comment: @JCCA This seemingly simple task to write into a stream is actually far more complex than when we write into a file (where we can be sure, all bytes will be written in the usual case) - instead of a socket. I would suggest to look for NSStream programming guides and example code that can be used as is as a solution. Also taking a look into how file descriptors work in general (which is all C and UNIX stuff).  Basically, your "write" API would become asynchronous and will include returning errors.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Understood! Appreciate the input, thank you a lot!